# d3 force diagrams node positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I am working with d3 force diagrams at the moment, I am wanting to plot my child nodes around a parent node equally spaced, so for example if I have a parent node, and 4 linked child nodes, I would want each those node positioned at 90 degree intervals? Is that possible?

Here is my current force code,

```
app.force
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(app.edges)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

function tick(e) {
   // console.log(link);
    var k = 6 * e.alpha;

    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });


    linkText
            .attr("x", function(d) {
                return ((d.source.x + d.target.x)/2);
            })
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return ((d.source.y + d.target.y)/2);
            });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y })
  }

app.force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-300)
    .linkDistance(85)
    .size([width, height]);

  //Where we will draw our visualisation
  app.svg = d3.select(".visualisation").append("svg")
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);
```

Answer (score 0):

`d3.layout.force()` was not created with such customisation in mind. Of course you can set some parameters, but most of the positions are automatic calculated, and changing them can be very difficult (unless you create your own force function). Version 4.x is better in that matter, but not much.

In your specific case, you can set a very high (mathematically speaking, "very low", since it is negative) charge:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-3000)
```

But even doing that the angles are not exactly right angles, and they vary: if you click "run snippet" you can get an almost perfect cross, but if you click it again it's not that perfect the next time. And it will not work as expected if you have data with several levels of depth.

Here is a demo:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js?2.9.3"></script>
<style>
    .link {
        stroke: #aaa;
    }
    .node text {
        stroke: #333;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .node circle {
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 3px;
        fill: #555;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <script>
        var width = 400,
            height = 300

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .distance(50)
            .charge(-3000)
            .size([width, height]);

        var json = {
            "nodes": [{
                "name": "node1"
            }, {
                "name": "node2"
            }, {
                "name": "node3"
            }, {
                "name": "node4"
            }, {
                "name": "node5"
            }],
            "links": [{
                "source": 0,
                "target": 1
            }, {
                "source": 0,
                "target": 2
            }, {
                "source": 0,
                "target": 3
            }, {
                "source": 0,
                "target": 4
            }]
        };

        force
            .nodes(json.nodes)
            .links(json.links)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(json.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", 2);

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(json.nodes)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(force.drag);

        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 8);

        node.append("text")
            .attr("dx", 12)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.name
            });

        force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.x;
                })
                .attr("y1", function(d) {
                    return d.source.y;
                })
                .attr("x2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                })
                .attr("y2", function(d) {
                    return d.target.y;
                });

            node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });
        });
    </script>
```